# pandas: index out of bounds using ix, but I can see the column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have no idea why pandas is throwing an index out of bounds on this dataframe:

```
SC7a        2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014
Region 10   10.1    10.6    11.1    11.6    9.7     10.8
Georgia     7.5     7.4     7.8     7.6     7.2     7.1
```

All I am doing is calling:

```
df.ix[:, 2014]
```

And I get this error:

```
IndexError: index 2014 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
```

Note that calling loc works just fine:

```
df.loc[:, 2014]
SC7a
Region 10    10.8
Georgia       7.1
Name: 2014, dtype: float64
```

Is this a bug? Shouldn't df.loc and df.ix be interchangeable with this data?

Comment: What is `print df.columns` ?

Comment: Index([2009, u'2010', u'2011', 2012, 2013, 2014], dtype='object')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `df.columns.dtype` is of the *object* data type and also that testing `df.columns.is_integer()` returns false.

The behaviour of `ix` is dependent on the data type or contents of the index. If you have an *integer* type index or `.is_integer()` is true, `ix` uses label-based indexing (like `loc`). If you have another type of index (e.g. *float*, *object*), then `ix` uses position-based indexing when given an integer to find (like `iloc`). In this latter case, index position 2014 is out of bounds.

If you convert your columns to integer type, `ix` will work as you expect it to (it will only use label-based indexing):

```
>>> df.columns = df.columns.astype(int)
>>> df.ix[:, 2014]
Region 10    10.8
Georgia       7.1
Name: 2014, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That was a much clearer description than in the docs, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is because all of your columns are integers.  Per the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing):

> .ix supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily label based, but will fall back to integer positional access unless
>   the corresponding axis is of integer type. .ix is the most general and
>   will support any of the inputs in .loc and .iloc. .ix also supports
>   floating point label schemes. .ix is exceptionally useful when dealing
>   with mixed positional and label based hierarchical indexes.
>
> However, when an axis is integer based, ONLY label based access and not positional access is supported. Thus, in such cases, it’s
>   usually better to be explicit and use .iloc or .loc.